# How to copy a vector except one specific element?

Tags: c++, vector, stl

I have a vector with some values. How can I copy it to another vector, so all the values but a specific one (located at position `x` - `x` will be a parameter of course) would be copied?

Moreover, I would like to use the value from location `x` for something else, so I prefer it will be saved.

Is there an easy way to do it?

Comment: Make a copy and then use `erase`.

Comment: Your question title is misleading. Your title asks about copying all but a specific *value*, but your question seems to ask about copying all but a specific *element*.

Comment: Bonus point for an answer that shows how to create an `InputIterator` that wraps `v.begin()` and which I can plug in as the first argument to `std::copy`. :-)

Answer (score 5):

> How to copy stl vector except one specific value?

You can use [`std::copy_if`](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/algorithm/copy):

```
std::vector<T> v = ....;
std::vector<T> out;
T x = someValue;
std::copy_if(v.begin(), v.end(), std::back_inserter(out), 
             [x](const T& t) { return t != x; });
```

If you don't have C++11 support, you can use [`std::remove_copy_if`](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/algorithm/remove_copy) and adjust the predicate's logic accordingly.

Comment: Note: if there are copies of `someValue`, they'll *all* be removed.  This probably isn't what you want if you just want to remove the object at a given index.

Comment: @cHao I realised that OP probably wants something else. The title of the question does not reflect its real intent.

Answer (score 1):

As Luchian suggests, you should use erase()

```
#include <vector>
#include <iostream>
#include<algorithm>

int main(){

    std::vector<int> vec1;
    vec1.push_back(3);
    vec1.push_back(4); // X in your question
    vec1.push_back(5);

    std::vector<int> new_vec;
    new_vec = vec1;

    new_vec.erase(std::find(new_vec.begin(),new_vec.end(),4));

    for (unsigned int i(0); i < new_vec.size(); ++i)
        std::cout << new_vec[i] << std::endl;

    return 0;
}
```

and for your second question, to determine the index of an element in a vector

```
 // determine the index of 4 ( in your case X)
 std::vector<int>::iterator it;
 it = find(vec1.begin(), vec1.end(), 4);
 std::cout << "position of 4: " << distance(vec1.begin(),it) << std::endl;
```

Answer (score 1):

use `std::copy_if` if you have c++11, otherwise:

```
void foo(int n) {
    std::vector<int> in;
    std::vector<int> out;

    std::copy(in.begin(), in.begin() + n, out.end());
    std::copy(in.begin() + n + 1, in.end(), out.end());
}
```

This works because `std::vector` has random-access iterators.